# Relacion one to many usando laravel resources

Tags: laravel-8

estoy iniciando una api en laravel en su version 8 y tambien soy nueva tanto en las apis como en el framework. Estuve investigando sobre los recursos de api y como manejarlos asi como tambien las relaciones. Lo que deseo hacer es registrar a una persona y asignarle un rol. Mi problema es que no se como dar de alta un registro usando el recurso mas la relacion. Uso POSTMAN como pruebas y el error que me sale al mandar es ""message": "Method Illuminate\Http\Request::rol does not exist.",
"exception": "BadMethodCallException""

Modelo ROL:

```
 namespace App\Models;

class Role extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    // relaciono modelos
    public function personas()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Persona::class);

    }

    protected $fillable = ['id', 'nombre_rol'];


}
```

Modelo PERSONA:

```
namespace App\Models;

class Persona extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    // relaciono modelos
    public function rol()
    {

        return $this->belongsTo(Role::class);

    }

    protected $fillable = ['nombres', 'apellidos', 'email', 'rol_id'];

    protected $hidden = ['clave'];


}
```

Persona Resource:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class PersonaResource extends JsonResource
{
    
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return[

            'id' => $this->id,
            'nombres' => $this->nombres,
            'apellidos' => $this->apellidos,
            'email' => $this->email,
            'clave' => $this->clave,
            'rol_id' => RoleResource::collection($this->rol)

        ];
    }
}
```

Persona Controller:

```
class PersonaController extends Controller
{
    
    public function index()
    {
        // retorna todos los registros
        return PersonaResource::collection(Persona::all());
    }

    

    
    public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $persona = Persona::create([
            'nombres' => $request->nombres,
            'apellidos' => $request->apellidos,
            'email' => $request->email,
            'clave' => $request->clave,
            'rol_id' => $request->rol()->id,// linea del error
            
          ]);
    
          return new PersonaResource($persona);
        


    }
```

Los datos en el postman los envio de esta manera:
{
"nombres": "juan",
"apellidos": "perez",
"email": "juan@gmail.com",
"clave" : "esto es una prueba",
"rol_id":[
1
]

}

Comment: Intenta hacer un `dd($request)` en tu función `store` para ver que recibe, intenta también hacer un `dd($request->rol()` y un `dd($request->rol` creo que esta última es la que te debería devolver los datos del rol.

Comment: es que la entidad es "personal" y la propiedad deberia ser "rol" ... luego con un update o set ... deberia de actualizarce en la base de datos  ...